# Python Neural Network to optimize AUC

Tags: python, neural-network, auc

is there a Neural Network package in Python that allows to directly optimize AUC?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276933/good-open-source-neural-network-python-library - have a look at answers here, there are many packages for neural networks, not sure about optimizing AUC in them.